# I want understand .Net 6 Core StreamReader properties

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

I need to calculate MD5 for a file.

```
private string GetMD5(string file)
{
  using var md5 = MD5.Create();
  using var stream = new StreamReader(file);
  return (BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream.BaseStream)).Replace("-", string.Empty)).ToLower();
}

private string GetMD5_V2(string file)
{
  using var md5 = MD5.Create();
  using var stream = new StreamReader(file);
  **_ = stream.EndOfStream;**
  return (BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream.BaseStream)).Replace("-", string.Empty)).ToLower();
}

test()
{
  var fichier = "myFile.txt";
  var md5_1 = GetMD5(fichier);
  var md5_2 = GetMD5_V2(fichier);
}
```

When I run this code md5_1 and md5_2 is different. I not understand why when I read the propertie stream.EndOfStream this change the result of stream.BaseStream?

Comment: Just wondering, but if you use the [StreamReader(Stream, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamreader-ctor(system-io-stream-system-boolean)) overload with the second parameter set to false, does it create the same results? If you set `stream.BaseStream.Position = 0` after doing `_ = stream.EndOfStream`, does the second example in the question give the same result as the first?

Comment: Side note: for future questions consider if example you show does not look ridiculous like in this case. I understand that the code shown is [mre] and not related to the code you have to just show the problem, but creating StreamReader on a file only to access its `BaseStream` looks... unwise - you may want to pick something that makes more sense or at least explicitly clarify that code is purely an example.

Answer (score 0):

`StreamReader.EndOfStream` consumes some bytes from the underlying stream.

[Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,27a804c872881c54)

Specifically, it will read enough bytes to fill its own internal buffer. Since your MD5 is operating on that underlying stream and not on the `StreamReader`, the bytes sitting in that buffer are no longer available to the MD5 calculation.